# Finding date where conditions within 30 days has elapsed

Tags: mysql, sql, date

For my website, I have a loyalty program where a customer gets some goodies if they've spent $100 within the last 30 days. A query like below:

```
SELECT u.username, SUM(total-shipcost) as tot
    FROM orders o
        LEFT JOIN users u
        ON u.userident = o.user
    WHERE shipped = 1
    AND user = :user
    AND date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

`:user` being their user ID. Column 2 of this result gives how much a customer has spent in the last 30 days, if it's over 100, then they get the bonus.

I want to display to the user which day they'll leave the loyalty program. Something like "x days until bonus expires", but how do I do this?

Take today's date, March 16th, and a user's order history:

```
id | tot  |    date
-----------------------
84    38     2016-03-05
76    21     2016-02-29
74    49     2016-02-20
61    42     2015-12-28
```

This user is part of the loyalty program now but leaves it on March 20th. What SQL could I do which returns how many days (4) a user has left on the loyalty program?

If the user then placed another order:

```
id | tot  |    date
-----------------------
87    12     2016-03-09
```

They're still in the loyalty program until the 20th, so the days remaining doesn't change in this instance, but if the total were 50 instead, then they instead leave the program on the 29th (so instead of 4 days it's 13 days remaining). For what it's worth, I care only about 30 days prior to the current date. No consideration for months with 28, 29, 31 days is needed.

Some `create table` code:

```
create table users (
    userident int,
    username varchar(100)
);

insert into users values 
    (1, 'Bob');

create table orders (
    id int,
    user int,
    shipped int,
    date date,
    total decimal(6,2),
    shipcost decimal(3,2)
);

insert into orders values
    (84, 1, 1, '2016-03-05', 40.50, 2.50),
    (76, 1, 1, '2016-02-29', 22.00, 1.00),
    (74, 1, 1, '2016-02-20', 56.31, 7.31),
    (61, 1, 1, '2015-12-28', 43.10, 1.10);
```

An example output of what I'm looking for is:

```
userident | username | days_left
--------------------------------
    1          Bob        4
```

This is using March 16th as today for use with `DATE(NOW())` to remain consistent with the previous bits of the question.

Comment: Still not clear. Please post your `create table code` with some sample input and expected output.

Comment: for this you would need to do a query for each day and only keep those that sum less than 100

Comment: Unless the long, convoluted answers provided below are doing it for you, consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements and a desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to take the following steps (per user):

- join the *orders* table with itself to calculate sums for different (bonus) starting dates, for any of the starting dates that are in the last 30 days
- select from those records only those starting dates which yield a sum of 100 or more
- select from those records only the one with the most recent starting date: this is the start of the bonus period for the selected user.

Here is a query to do that:

```
SELECT      u.userident,
            u.username,
            MAX(base.date) AS bonus_start,
            DATE(MAX(base.date) + INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS bonus_expiry,
            30-DATEDIFF(NOW(), MAX(base.date)) AS bonus_days_left
FROM        users u
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT     o.user, 
                           first.date AS date,
                           SUM(o.total-o.shipcost) as tot
                FROM       orders first
                INNER JOIN orders o
                        ON o.user = first.user
                       AND o.shipped = 1
                       AND o.date >= first.date
                WHERE      first.shipped = 1
                       AND first.date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                GROUP BY   o.user,
                           first.date
                HAVING     SUM(o.total-o.shipcost) >= 100
            ) AS base
         ON base.user = u.userident
GROUP BY    u.username,
            u.userident
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db79d/4).

With this input as orders:

```
+----+------+---------+------------+-------+----------+
| id | user | shipped |    date    | total | shipcost |
+----+------+---------+------------+-------+----------+
| 61 |   1  |    1    | 2015-12-28 |   42  |    0     |
| 74 |   1  |    1    | 2016-02-20 |   49  |    0     |
| 76 |   1  |    1    | 2016-02-29 |   21  |    0     |
| 84 |   1  |    1    | 2016-03-05 |   38  |    0     |
| 87 |   1  |    1    | 2016-03-09 |   50  |    0     |
+----+------+---------+------------+-------+----------+
```

The above query will return this output (when executed on 2016-03-20):

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| userident | username | bonus_start | bonus_expiry | bonus_days_left |
+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
|       1   | John     | 2016-02-29  |  2016-03-30  |         10      |
+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Since I am fair player, I upvoted your solution. While doing very different queries, it is close to mine if I remove the VIEW layer. Obviously OP doesn't like views :(

Comment: I've chosen this answer because the task at hand was relatively complex considering my experience (or lackthereof); adding views into the mix just goes too over my head. This answer was clean and concise, and used things I'm more familiar with.

Comment: Thank you for the bonus, @gator!

Comment: @ThomasG, the views in itself should not pose a problem. However your query is not giving correct results in all situations as I have pointed out in a comment on your answer. In fact, none of the other answers produce the correct result (at the time of writing).

Comment: @Zohra does however describe a correct procedure to get the correct result, I commented on it as well.

Answer (score 4):

The following is basically how to do what you want. Note that references to "30 days" are rough estimates and what you may be looking for is "29 days" or "31 days" as works to get the exact date that you want.

1. Retrieve the list of dates and amounts that are still active, i.e., within the last 30 days (as you did in your example), as a table (I'll call it **Active**) like the one you showed.
2. Join that new table (**Active**) with the original table where a row from **Active** is joined to all of the rows of the original table using the *date* fields. Compute a total of the amounts from the original table. The new table would have a **Date** field from **Active** and a **Totol** field that is the sum of all the amounts in the joined records from the original table.
3. Select from the resulting table all records where the Amount is greater than 100.00 and create a new table with **Date** and the minimum **Amount** of those records.
4. Compute 30 days ahead from those dates to find the ending date of their loyalty program.

Comment: Nice solution. It should mention in step two that the records from the original table should have a date that is equal or greater than the date from the Active set. I suppose you intended that, but just forgot to mention it. So upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

### Simple solution

Seeing how you do your first query, I guessed that when you are at the point where you look for the "expiration date", you already know that the user meets the 100 points over last 30 days. Then you can do this :

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(MIN(date),INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
FROM orders o
WHERE shipped = 1
AND user = :user
AND date >= (DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

It takes the minimum order date of a user over the last 30 days, and add 30 days to the result.

But that really is a poor design to achieve what you want. 
You would better to think further and implement what's next.

---

### Advanced solution

In order to reproduce all the following solution, I have used the Fiddle that Trincot kindly built, and expanded it to test on more data : 4 users having 4 orders.

SQL FIddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/668939/1

---

**Step 1 : Design**

The following query will return all the users meeting the loyalty program criteria, along with their earlier order date within 30 days and the loyalty program expiration date  calculated from the earlier date, and the number of days before it expires.

```
SELECT O.user, u.username, SUM(total-shipcost) as tot, MIN(date) AS mindate, 
       DATE_ADD(MIN(date),INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS expirationdate, 
       DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(MIN(date),INTERVAL 30 DAY), DATE(NOW())) AS daysleft
FROM orders o      
    LEFT JOIN users u
    ON u.userident = o.user                         
WHERE shipped = 1                                              
AND date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY user
HAVING tot >= 100;
```

Now, create a **VIEW** with the above query

```
CREATE VIEW loyalty_program AS
    SELECT O.user, u.username, SUM(total-shipcost) as tot, MIN(date) AS mindate, 
           DATE_ADD(MIN(date),INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS expirationdate, 
           DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(MIN(date),INTERVAL 30 DAY), DATE(NOW())) AS daysleft
    FROM orders o      
        LEFT JOIN users u
        ON u.userident = o.user                         
    WHERE shipped = 1                                              
    AND date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    GROUP BY user
    HAVING tot >= 100;
```

It is important to understand that this is only a **one-shot** action on your database.

---

**Step 2 : Use your new VIEW**

Once you have the view, you can get easily, for all users, the "state" of the loyalty program:

```
SELECT * FROM loyalty_program

user    username    tot mindate                 expirationdate  daysleft
1           John    153 February, 28 2016       March, 29 2016  9
2           Joe     112 February, 24 2016       March, 25 2016  5
3           Jack    474 February, 23 2016       March, 24 2016  4
4           Averel  115 February, 22 2016       March, 23 2016  3
```

For a specific user, you can get the date you are looking for like this:

```
SELECT expirationdate FROM loyalty_program WHERE username='Joe'
```

You can also request all the users for which the expiration date is today

```
SELECT user FROM loyalty_program WHERE expirationdate=DATE(NOW))
```

But there are other easy possibilities that you'll discover after having played with your VIEW.

---

### Conclusion

Make your life easier: learn to use VIEWS !

Comment: Views are not required here, and would severely jeopardise performance

Comment: In case you have not read my answer correctly: I have proposed a simple and an avdanced solution. The simple solution answers the question with no view. What is yhe point of your comment?

Comment: Your query does not give the correct result (see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db79d/5). ) when on 2016-03-09 50 an order is logged for 50, as described in the question. Your query returns as expiry date 2016-03-21, but it should discard the order of 2016-02-20, because without it, the total is still > 100.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your table looks like this:

```
user | id | total |    date
-------------------------------
 12     84    38     2016-03-05
 12     76    21     2016-02-29
 23     74    49     2016-02-20
 23     61    42     2015-12-28
```

then try this:

```
SELECT x.user, x.date, x.id, x.cum_sum, d,date, DATEDIFF(NOW(), x.date) from (SELECT a.user, a.id, a.date, a.total, 
  (SELECT SUM(b.total) FROM order_table b WHERE b.date <= a.date and a.user=b.user ORDER BY b.user, b.id DESC) AS cum_sum FROM order_table a where a.date>=DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) ORDER BY a.user, a.id DESC) as x 
left join 
(SELECT c.user, c.date as start_date, c.id from (SELECT a.user, a.id, a.date, a.total, 
  (SELECT SUM(b.total) FROM order_table b WHERE b.date <= a.date and a.user=b.user ORDER BY b.user, b.id DESC) AS cum_sum FROM order_table a where a.date>=DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) ORDER BY a.user, a.id DESC) as c WHERE FLOOR(c.cum_sum/100)=MIN(FLOOR(c.cum_sum/100)) and MOD(c.cum_sum,100)=MAX(MOD(c.cum_sum,100)) group by concat(c.user, "_", c.id)) as d on concat(x.user, "_", x.id)=concat(d.user, "_", d.id) where x.date=d.date;
```

You will get a table something like this:

```
user |   Date      |    cum_sum     |   start_date  |   Time_left
    ----------------------------------------------------
  12    2016-03-05         423          2016-03-05      24
  13    2016-02-29         525          2016-02-29      12
  23    2016-02-20         944          2016-02-20       3
  29    2015-12-28         154          2015-12-28       4
```

i have not tested this. But what i am trying to do is to create a table in descending order of id and user, and get a cumulative total column along with it. I have created another table by using this table with cumulative total, with relevant date (i.e. date from which date difference is to be calculated) for each user. I have left joined these two tables, and put in the condition x.date=d.date. I have put start_date and date in the table to check if the query is working.

Also, this is not the most optimum way of writing this code, but i have tried to stay as safe as possible by using sub queries, since i did not have the data to test this. Let me know if you face any error.

Comment: The `left join on` clause is not syntactically correct -- the join condition is missing.